# All of my CSS files are being imported into my React JS file, but I didn't import them?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have found some strange issue while making my website with React.

I have organized my filesystem into a folder of components-js and components-css with corresponding Text.js and Text.css files to match up.

[image: Filesystem Setup]

Below are my Login.js/css and Signup.js/css files.

**Login.js**

```
import '../components-css/Login.css';
import Logo from './Logo.js';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useNavigate, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import TextInput from './TextInput.js';


function Login(props) {

    const [error, setError] = useState(false);

    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const trigger_error = () => {
        console.log(error)

        if (error === false) {
            setError(true);
        }
        else {
            setError(false);
        }
    }


    const check_login_info = () => {
        // TODO: Insert code here to check for username and password match
        navigate('/Jobs')
    }

    return (
        <div className='login-card'>
            <div className='login-card-image'>
            </div>
            <div className='login-contents'>
                <Logo/>
                <div className='login-contents-header'>
                    Sign In
                    {error ? <p className='error'>Invalid Login. Please try again.</p>: <></>}
                </div>
                <TextInput label={'Email'}/>
                <TextInput label={'Password'}/>
                <input type='button' className='submit' onClick={() => check_login_info()} value='Log In'/>
                <div className='bottom_text'>
                    New to Product? <Link className='sign-up' to='/signup'>Sign Up</Link>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )

};

export default Login;
```

**Login.css**

```
.login-card {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 90%;
    width: 90%;
    padding: 0px;
    justify-content: center; 
    align-items: center;
    display:flex;

}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
    /* CSS that should be displayed if width is equal to or less than 800px goes here */
    .login-card {
        flex-direction: column-reverse; 
    }
}

@media (min-width:800px) {
    .login-card { 
        flex-direction: row;     
    }
    
}

/* Uncomment for card-style background image */
.login-card-image {
    background-image: url('../images/login-background-3.jpg');
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    /* border-radius: 20px; */
    
}

.login-contents {
    display: flex;
    padding: 10%;
    width: 50%;
    flex-direction: column;
    /* background-color: red; */
}


@media (min-width:800px) {
    .login-contents-header {
        margin: 5%;
        padding: 5%;
        font-size: 30px;
        height: 50%;
        justify-content: center;
        text-align: center;
    }

   
}

@media (max-width:800px) {
    .login-contents-header {
        margin: 5%;
        padding: 5%;
        padding-bottom: 0px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
        font-size: 20px;
        height: 50%;
        justify-content: center;
        text-align: center;
    }


}

.login-contents span {
    padding-top: 40px;
}

/* CSS */
.submit {

  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgb(202, 225, 246);
  border-radius: 12px;
  box-shadow: transparent 0 0 0 3px,rgba(18, 18, 18, .1) 0 6px 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #121212;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  font-family: Inter,sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  justify-content: center;
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 10%;
  margin-left: 25%;
  outline: none;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: box-shadow .2s,-webkit-box-shadow .2s;
  width: 50%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 0;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  touch-action: manipulation;
}

.submit:hover {
  box-shadow: rgb(148, 179, 206) 0 0 0 3px, transparent 0 0 0 0;
}

.submit {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.bottom_text {
    /* background-color: red; */
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
}

.sign-up {
    color: rgb(26, 158, 202);
    text-decoration: none;
}

.error {
    color: red;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
```

**Signup.js**

```
import '../components-css/Signup.css'
import Logo from '../components-js/Logo.js';
import TextInput from './TextInput.js';
import Back from '../images/arrow.png';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'

function Signup() {
    return (
        <div className='signup'>
            <div className='signup-form-container'>
                <div className='signup-form-padding'>
                    <div className='back'>
                        <Link to='/'>
                            <img src={Back} alt='backarrow' width='100%' height='80%'/>
                        </Link>
                    </div>
                    <div className='logo'>
                        <Logo/>
                    </div>
                    <div className='header'>
                        Create Account
                    </div>
                    <div className='form-container'>
                        <form className='form'>
                            <TextInput label={'First Name'}/>
                            <TextInput label={'Last Name'}/>
                            <TextInput label={'Email'}/>
                            <TextInput label={'Phone Number'}/>
                            <TextInput label={'Password'}/>
                            <TextInput label={'Confirm Password'}/>
                        </form>
                        <input className='submit' type='submit' value='Submit'></input>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Signup;
```

**Signup.css**

```
.signup {
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
    /* background-color: red; */
    position:absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
}

.signup-form-container {
    height: 85%;
    width: 40%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 3%;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 50px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.signup-form-padding {
    height: 90%;
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 5%;
    /* background-color: red; */
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
}

.back {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
}

.back img{
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}

.logo {
    height: 11%;
    width: 70%;
    margin:auto;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    /* background-color: red; */
}

.header {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
}



.form {
    width: 60%;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-bottom: -50px;

}

.form input {
   margin-top: 0px;
   margin-left: 0px;
}

.submit {
}
```

When rendering my Signup page, it somehow uses the css from Login.css to show the Submit button. Upon further inspection, it appears the browser is loading ALL of my css files, one by one (in the  on the screenshot below). I noticed this by looking at the inspector on the browser itself:
[image: Rendering of the page]

[image]

What is happening? I'm not sure why it seems to render all of the styles at once.

Comment: This is not an issue. Is an expected and desired behavior. Look you have two components such as ButtonSuccess and ButtonError when presented into a page you want their styles are presents to document. So you must create classes with very particular names to avoid overrides. Such .button-success-container, instead of button-container

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is expected. ESM imports, including CSS via things like Webpack are *static* imports. They will be loaded as soon as the bundle loads, and it doesn't matter if the component you imported it in is loaded or not. It's included because somewhere in your code you import login, as well as signup -- so the CSS imports are resolved in one go.

Css-in-js libs like `styled-components` *do* only load the styles if the relevant component is rendered. Static CSS importing is not really css-in-js. Those are globally provided. You might consider those solutions if you want better scoping of styles.

You could also consider CSS modules.

Comment: I've adopted lazy load approach and these undesired effects are avoid. But when you have small components inside same page you will face issues. So this answer solve your problem. Thanks @adam thomas

Answer (score -1):

One very easy way to solve this would be to start using Sass and wrap all your CSS for a given page in class names and then within your pages, apply the class name to the outermost `div`.

To enable Sass support:

```bash
npm install sass --save-dev
```

Then rename your `.css` files to `.scss` and update imports.

**Login.scss**

```scss
.login-card {
  // all styes specific to login page go here
}
```

**Signup.scss**

```scss
.signup {
  // all styles specific to signup page go here
}
```

Comment: While this may help decrease style collisions, how does it avoid eager loading?

Comment: It only makes the selectors more specific. I didn't mean to say it will do code splitting @ghybs