# Why all the SCSS files are imported to every component? - ReactJs

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, reactjs, sass

React 18.2.0

I have my code like this

## Onboarding.jsx

```
import "../../styles/screens/_onboarding.scss";


export default function Onboarding({ setPaymentSuccess }) {
  return (
    <div className="card">
      <div className="banner"></div>
      <div className="content">
        <div className="logo">
          <img src={logo} alt="" />
        </div>
```

## CreateAccount.jsx

```
import "../../styles/screens/_createAccount.scss";

export default function CreateAccount() {
  return (
    <div className="card">
      <div className="banner"></div>
      <div className="content">
        <div className="logo">
          <img src={logo} alt="" />
          <span className="caption">Baker's Fifa Snipe Bot</span>
        </div>

        <div className="hairline"></div>
        <div className="text-content">
          <div className="text-caption">Terms of Service</div>
          <div className="text-paragraph">
            <span className="link">Continue reading...</span>
          </div>
        </div>
```

And

## Purchase.jsx

```
import "../styles/pages/_purchase.scss";

export default function Purchase() {
  const [paymentSuccess, setPaymentSuccess] = useState(false);
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <div className="container">
        {!paymentSuccess && (
          <Onboarding setPaymentSuccess={setPaymentSuccess} />
        )}
        {paymentSuccess && <CreateAccount />}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

It doesn't matter what component is loaded, I can see both of these stylesheets are loaded like this.

[image]

Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here?
Thank you!

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/73349189/1086398

Comment: Thank you @AdamThomas does this happen all the time? I've worked on some other projects but this didn't happen as I remember. I'm sorry I'm still learning

Comment: If imported like this without any lazy loading (which they might have had) then yes, its normal. If they used lazy loading youd see it loaded later, but also it wouldnt go away when it unmounts. To get that behaviour you need a css-in-js lib.